# Index out of bounds while trying to collect Labels in a List

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I'm trying to declare `Label`s with a `List`.
I'm getting an index out of bounds error.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Player_editor
{
partial class Form3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        labels[1] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        labels[2] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        labels[3] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        labels[4] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        labels[5] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        labels[6] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        labels[1].AutoSize = true;
        labels[1].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 9);
        labels[1].Name = "label1";
        labels[1].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        labels[1].TabIndex = 0;
        labels[1].Text = "label1";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        labels[2].AutoSize = true;
        labels[2].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(53, 9);
        labels[2].Name = "label2";
        labels[2].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        labels[2].TabIndex = 1;
        labels[2].Text = "label2";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        labels[3].AutoSize = true;
        labels[3].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 22);
        labels[3].Name = "label3";
        labels[3].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        labels[3].TabIndex = 2;
        labels[3].Text = "label3";
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        labels[4].AutoSize = true;
        labels[4].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(53, 22);
        labels[4].Name = "label4";
        labels[4].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        labels[4].TabIndex = 3;
        labels[4].Text = "label4";
        // 
        // label5
        // 
        labels[5].AutoSize = true;
        labels[5].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 35);
        labels[5].Name = "label5";
        labels[5].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        labels[5].TabIndex = 4;
        labels[5].Text = "label5";
        // 
        // label6
        // 
        labels[6].AutoSize = true;
        labels[6].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(53, 35);
        labels[6].Name = "label6";
        labels[6].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 13);
        labels[6].TabIndex = 5;
        labels[6].Text = "label6";
        // 
        // Form3
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(239, 464);
        this.Controls.Add(labels[6]);
        this.Controls.Add(labels[5]);
        this.Controls.Add(labels[4]);
        this.Controls.Add(labels[3]);
        this.Controls.Add(labels[2]);
        this.Controls.Add(labels[1]);
        this.Name = "Form3";
        this.Text = "Groups";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form3_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    List<System.Windows.Forms.Label> labels = new List<System.Windows.Forms.Label>();
}
}
```

Comment: You should not be adding your own code in this section; it is auto-generated by the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the labels to the list by calling the `Add` method.

Note that lists use zero-based indices.

---

Also note that the designer will silently drop all of that code.

Instead, you should leave the designer-generated code untouched, then add the `Label` instances to a `List<Label>` in your constructor.

Comment: it will work, his code will disappear the next time he changes something.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `List<T>.Add(T object)` method to add something to a list. Besides that, your custom code with disappear the next time you change something in the designer, as the `form.designer.cs` is autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a List, you add elements to it using the Add() method; it looks like you are trying to add elements by using the list indexer (list[1] = new Label) but there is no element at that index.

Also, you should be careful to start your indexing at 0 (the first element is at index 0, etc...).

Finally, I would agree with the other post that you should stay away from editing the designer files, and instead put your code elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Add method, plus you're better working with an implementation of List like linkedlist or arraylist rather than the interface "List" itself.